# Order of WP page load (including widgets, php, plugins, media, templates, and CSS)

Tags: css, scripts

In what order does WordPress resources *(e.g. templates, php files, media, plugins, widgets, enqueued scripts, and CSS)* get loaded?

I am new to WordPress and there is some basic info I have been unable to find on this forum; I was wondering if someone might be able to describe the order in which various resources like templates, PHP files, media,  plugins, widgets, enqueued scripts, and CSS are loaded in WordPress.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files) asks about plugins only, but it would be helpful to know about how a page is loaded, from start to finish, so learners can get an idea about the entire rendering process.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) asks users to provide a flow chart about the load order. I am requesting three things that are different;

1. I would like to have plugins and widgets explictly addressed.
2. I would also like people to answer the question, and answer it using words and/or images, I am not specifically asking for a flow chart.
3. I am also asking that respondents make an effort to avoid going into too much detail, so beginners can get a good sense of the most important parts of the loading process.

Any information is helpful, including reference links, however, those comprehensive guides are already online. *The problem is that for new users, they are dense, long, and not easy to understand.* I'm hoping a community member can provide an answer that gives a nice, well-rounded overview of the process, without listing every single detail that one can look up in the online guides.

Comment: [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/71406/11761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First plugins are loaded, then templates.

Media is not loaded until called (afaik) from either a plugin or theme.

Widgets, enqueued scripts and CSS can be called from both plugins and templates so it depends where they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about Template Hierarchy on the developer handbook
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/