# Which functions in theme or plugin load first

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, customization

I created a plugin to override a theme's function. As I learn that function in plugin loads first but I got an error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wooc_extra_register_fields() (previously
>   declared in ****/themes/****/functions.php:247) in
>   ***/plugins/custom-plugin/custom-plugin.php on line 89

Not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Also put theme's functions need to be override in if !function exist.
So what is the right way to override a theme function wrap in !function exist using a plugin??

Comment: Please have a look on this solution,
[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first) [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files)

Comment: that what I learnt. Plugins are loaded first but why I get redeclare error???

Answer (score 1):

```
In wp-settings.php, WordPress first checks for any must-use plugins (plugins in the optional mu-plugins folder) and loads those.
```

Then, if you're running a multisite installation, it checks for plugins that are network-activated and loads those.

Answer (score 1):

For your situation it would be best to wrap the plugin in `function_exists`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wooc_extra_register_fields' ) ) {
    function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
    }
}
```

in the parent theme, as this makes the functions of the theme pluggable. You can then create a child theme and redeclare the function in the child theme's `functions.php`

Comment: I already do wrap theme function on !function_exists. but the functions in theme are loaded before plugin so it doesn't help

Comment: Tunji is correct. If you put the code in the child theme, it's functions.php will be loaded before the parent's functions.php