# How to re-arrange this hooked content?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am trying to re-arrange Woocommerce Sensei hooked content. Basically, I would like to have `course_image` at the top (high priority).

```
// code in sensei /includes/hooks/template.php

<?php
        /**
         * Fires just before the course content in the content-course.php file.
         *
         * @since 1.9
         *
         * @param integer $course_id
         *
         * @hooked Sensei_Templates::the_title          - 5
         * @hooked Sensei()->course->course_image       - 10
         * @hooked  Sensei()->course->the_course_meta   - 20
         */
        do_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', get_the_ID() );
        ?>
```

I added: `remove_action( 'sensei_course_content_inside_before', 'course_image', 10);` in my Theme's `function.php` but it doesn't work.

How do I re-arrange above `title, image and meta`?

Please suggest.

**Update**

```
//code called add_action
// add course content title to the courses on the archive page
add_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( 'Sensei_Templates', 'the_title' ) ,5, 1 );

// add the course image above the content
add_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( $this->course, 'course_image' ) ,10, 1 ); //if I change 10 to 4 in their code directly, it works
```

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/blob/master/includes/hooks/template.php#L53)

**UPDATE 2**

I get following on:

```
global $wp_filter;
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $wp_filter['sensei_course_content_inside_before'] );
echo '</pre>';

//output
WP_Hook Object
(
    [callbacks] => Array
        (

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Sensei_Templates::the_title] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Sensei_Templates
                                    [1] => the_title
                                )

                            [accepted_args] => 1
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0000000032a2e99b00007fe8c14d85d0the_course_meta] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WooThemes_Sensei_Course Object
                                        (
                                            [token] => course
                                            [meta_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => course_prerequisite
                                                    [1] => course_featured
                                                    [2] => course_video_embed
                                                    [3] => course_woocommerce_product
                                                )

                                            [my_courses_page] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => the_course_meta
                                )

                            [accepted_args] => 1
                        )
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0000000032a2e99b00007fe8c14d85d0course_image] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WooThemes_Sensei_Course Object
                                        (
                                            [token] => course
                                            [meta_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => course_prerequisite
                                                    [1] => course_featured
                                                    [2] => course_video_embed
                                                    [3] => course_woocommerce_product
                                                )

                                            [my_courses_page] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => course_image
                                )

                            [accepted_args] => 1
                        )

                )

                    [0000000032a2e99b00007fe8c14d85d0content_before_backwards_compatibility_hooks] => Array
                        (
                            [function] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WooThemes_Sensei_Course Object
                                        (
                                            [token] => course
                                            [meta_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => course_prerequisite
                                                    [1] => course_featured
                                                    [2] => course_video_embed
                                                    [3] => course_woocommerce_product
                                                )

                                            [my_courses_page] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => content_before_backwards_compatibility_hooks
                                )

                            [accepted_args] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [iterations:WP_Hook:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_priority:WP_Hook:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [nesting_level:WP_Hook:private] => 0
    [doing_action:WP_Hook:private] => 
)
```

Comment: Where did you add the `remove_action()` code? Maybe the action wasn't added yet (in terms of code execution order)

Comment: I have added in `theme/my-theme/functions.php`.

Comment: Can you add the code corresponding to this to the question? You'll probaby have something like `add_action('init', 'my_func');` with `my_func` having the `remove_action()`, right? Try `add_action('init', 'my_function', 99);` instead - but it depends on how/when Sensei adds the action, I don't know that

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override action that use in plugin, use can wrap the `remove_action` code in `template_redirect` action to make sure your action will be excute later.

For example

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {

    // Remove the title.
    remove_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( 'Sensei_Templates', 'the_title' ) ,5, 1 );

    // Add it again
    add_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( 'Sensei_Templates', 'the_title' ) ,15, 1 );
}, 11 );
```

If it doesn't work, you can try to increase priority form `11` to something greater.

Note that if your PHP version doesn't support anonymous function, you need to change the wrap function to a named function.

**UPDATE**

Why `template_redirect`?

Because it's hard to know (IMO) the order of action that plugins excute, so we can try to catch up the order of all actions later, after all of them has been add/remove. `template_redirect` is one of "later" actions that can help use re-order the actions because this action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load.

**UPDATE 2**

You can try this code for `course_image`:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {

    // Remove the image.
    remove_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( Sensei()->course, 'course_image' ), 10, 1);

    // Add it again
    add_action('sensei_course_content_inside_before', array( Sensei()->course, 'course_image' ), 1, 1 );
}, 11 );
```

Comment: Can you elaborate (by editing the answer), why you advise using the `template_redirect` action?

Comment: @kero I did that, please check my update ;)

Comment: Makes sense. I try to be precise (if I have the time): If we [search through the repository](https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/search?q="template.php"&unscoped_q="template.php"), we'll see where exactly the file is loaded: `Sensei_Main->load_hooks()`, which in turn is called from `Sensei_Main->__construct()`, which is then [called from the root file](https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/blob/a8c49c65220830865dc380416551e5b2cebba895/woothemes-sensei.php#L48) (via `Sensei_Main::instance()`). Which, in turn, isn't called via an action at all :(

Comment: Not a best practice (in my opinion). If it were called from another action, we could've used that exact same hook with higher priority

Comment: I must change the priority of `course_image` unfortunately. Because, there are other hooks too. With this redirect, only title is going below the image, which requires to add bunch of functions for each hooks. So, better I should change the priority of `course_image`.

Comment: Please check my update, filter output.

Comment: You can always change the image instead. I will update my answer @AdarshKhatri

Comment: That update doesn't work. No effect at all.

Comment: Oh, I got wrong class name, try `Sensei_Course` instead of `Sensei_Main`

Comment: Yes, I tried with that. It throws: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in sensei/includes/class-sensei-course.php on line 870`, if post has no feature image.

Comment: Does it work with post that has featured image?

Comment: Small trick for loading the action after all other plugins in case you need to do this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files/272889#272889 (see the last comment in this post).

Comment: @TungDu it adds image at top, but it doesn't remove the image.

Comment: @TungDu ok, instead of `'Sensei_Course'` it is `Sensei()->course`. Please update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you found it @Adarsh Khatri