# Buddypress function and global $bp question

Tags: plugin-development, buddypress

I have a question regarding Buddypress tweak.

I can use any Buddypress function when I make a plugin without any include or require functions.

How is it possible? Because Buddypress loads faster than my plugin?

In addition, What does global $bp mean? Withou this global $bp, I can use any buddypress functions, so why does it need?

I'm newbie to development. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins [load alphabetically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63146/7355) by default. If Buddypress is alphbetically before your plugins folder name, then Buddypress will load first and it's functions will be available. Additionally, whatever functionality depends on another plugins you can always attach to the `plugins_loaded` hook, which fires after all plugins are finished loading. For example:

```
/**
 * Runs code after plugins have finished loading
 *
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_plugins_loaded() {

    die( 'Plugins have finished loading.' );

}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'prefix_plugins_loaded' );
```

[PHP Globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) are common in Plugins and WordPress. The `$bp` global is simply a variable that likely holds a required object needed by the specific plugin function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It helps a lot! :)